# Getting seg fault when trying to decrement my environment variable in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf

Total C noob here. I know there is something wrong with my `sprintf_wrapper` method because before I introduced it everything was working fine. The point of the function is to take a string buffer and a number and change the string buffers value to "WHALE=[num]". I then use this new string with `putenv` method.

The code results in **"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"**, I believe it occurs after sprintf_wrapper is called.

## Main Method

```
int main(void) {
    getP0Info();
    putenv("WHALE=7");
    forkProcesses();

    int whale = atoi(getenv("WHALE"));
    char new_env[50];
    sleep(1);
    printf("P0: %d\n", whale);
    whale = whale - 1;
    sprintf_wrapper(new_env, whale);
    putenv(new_env);

    return 0;
}
```

## sprintf_wrapper

```
void sprintf_wrapper(char* str, int num) {
    char buffer[10];
    str = "WHALE=";
    sprintf(buffer,"%d", num);
    strcat(str,buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning a string constant to the `str` variable, then attempting to to append to it.  Because string constants typically live in read only memory, this commonly causes a core dump.

Do this instead:

```
void sprintf_wrapper(char* str, int num) {
    sprintf(str,"WHALE=%d", num);
}
```

Comment: It would be super awesome to use `snprintf` and ensure that you're never going to exceed the bounds of that array.

Answer (score 0):

```
sprintf_wrapper(new_env, whale);
```

You are appending to a string literal, which is read-only memory.

This generates a segmentation fault because you write into memory that is not supposed to be written into.

```
str = "WHALE=";
```

Thats a read only string literal.